# Create Unmanaged package with dependencies

Tags: deployment, package, unlocked-package, unmanaged-package

I have a commonly used object let's say object A it is being referenced in lookup's and formula fields. I have to create an unmanaged package without including "object A" how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. We will have to use Org-Dependent Unlocked Packages. These packages are designed for specific production and sandbox orgs. You can install them only in orgs that contain the metadata that the package depends on.

Refer [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_org_dependent.htm) link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is not really possible. If a reference is being created, you cannot just exclude it from the package. The package compilation will fail in such scenarios.

For your use case, you can create an **unlocked** Package with just object A and then create a dependent package with other components (This new package has dependency to Package with Object A).

To learn more about dependent packages, checkout EasySpaces app [sfdx-project.json](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc/blob/develop/sfdx-project.json)